# Git: keep branch names and paths the same during cloning between remotes

Tags: git, git-branch

How do I clone repositories between GitLab servers keeping branch names and paths consistent?

I use the following sequence to clone repositories between GitLab servers, with local git client in the middle:

```
git clone <source URL>
for /F %R in ('git branch -r') do git branch --track %R %R
git fetch --all
git pull --all
git fetch --tags
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <target URL>
git push --all
git push --tags
```

But this sequence changes branch paths and creates branches that did not exist on the source server.

Saying I have a repo in source GitLab with 2 branches:

```
* branch1
  branch2
```

(here and below the star marks the default branch)

when I clone a repo to my local machine with `git clone`, I got two extra branches, related to the default one at the source server:

```
* branch1
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/branch1
  remotes/origin/branch1
  remotes/origin/branch2
```

After `git branch --track` the number of branches grows to 7:

```
* branch1
  origin/HEAD
  origin/branch1
  origin/branch2
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> remotes/origin/branch1
  remotes/origin/branch1
  remotes/origin/branch2
```

More, new HEAD branch (origin/HEAD) is not related to any of branch1 branches anymore.

Finally, when I remove old origin and add a new one, I get:

```
* branch1
  origin/HEAD
  origin/branch1
  origin/branch2
```

And this is exactly what will be pushed to the target GitLab server. With one branch having two duplicates ('branch1', 'origin/branch1' and 'origin/HEAD'), and another one changed it's path ('branch2' -> 'origin/branch2').

Here I can delete 'extra' branches and rename all branches manually before pushing them to the target server. But this becomes a headache when there are hundreds of branches in a repo.

Though I can write a script to remove 'origin/' from names of all these branches before pushing, I feel like inventing a bicycle. Is there an easier way to get branch names in target GitLab exactly the same as they were in the source GitLab?

Comment: Git doesn't really deal with "paths" here: branch names *act like* path names (and Git sometimes stores them in file system entities) but they're not actually path names. But in general if you're copying a repository with `git clone` *and* you want to copy the *names* database as well as the commits-and-other-objects database, you want `--mirror`. You'd do one mirror clone from source and one mirror push to destination (and then delete the intermediate mirror). Note that this won't copy the Git*Lab* database of issues, MRs, etc.

Comment: Thanks torek, sure, I understand that these are not real paths, I just refer them such for more 'human-friendly' explanation. I could call them namespaces probably, just slashes are more often associated with pathes. Let me try the --mirror syntax. I don't care about anything except code repository here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: all credentials to torek who described the proper approach in a comment, not in an answer. But I know that you guys who seek for answers look for accepted answers first. ;)*

So, the --mirror parameter does the job, and the sequence is:

```
git clone <source URL> --mirror
<here you might want to copy it to some new subfolder>
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <target URL>
git push origin --mirror
```